# Python & Rest API of 2.4.6

Tags: magento2.4.6, oauth

The code I used for my 2.4.2 Installation no longer works in my 2.4.6 Installation.
It seems they deprecated HMAC-SHA1 in favour of HMAC-SHA256.

requests_oauthlib doesn't support HMAC-SHA256 as far as I can see. I can't get anything else to work (authomatic, OAuthLib,...).

Can anybody help with some code snippets how to connect to 2.4.6 with python?

Comment: explain with code, what code or something you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it!

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session    
...
client_key = config["consumer_key"]
client_secret = config["consumer_secret"]
resource_owner_key = config["access_token"]
resource_owner_secret = config["access_token_secret"]
# Create OAuth1 session with HMAC-SHA256 for Magento
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key,
                      client_secret=client_secret,
                      resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
                      resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
                      signature_method='HMAC-SHA256')
```

With this oath session I can finally talk to my Magento 2.4.6.